# How can I make that the ui text will be in front of anything else?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want that the text to be always on the top left corner and always above in front of anything else, objects ui everything.

I want to use this ui text for saving message.

Screenshot of the Canvas settings and where the text is show in the scene window and the game window :

[image: Canvas settings]

And the text settings using Text - TextMeshPro :

[image: Text settings]

Comment: Aint the UI layer is rendered on the top by default?

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. Camera-space UI draws on top of everything except other camera-space UI objects and screen-space UI
2. Screen-space UI draws on top of everything except other screen-space UI objects
3. Your objects is attached to a World-space canvas

While *in theory* you could fiddle with drawing order with shaders, this does not apply to UI objects (as the world is rendered first, then camera-space UI, then other cameras and their UIs, then screen-space UI).

As such you will not be able to make that text draw "in front" of anything else. It exists in 3D space and is subject to all of the rules that that entails, such as being behind screen-space canvases.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your text material [up in the render queue](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-renderQueue.html) if the defaults aren't working for you.